# How to filter items in a Vaadin 8 Treegrid?

Tags: vaadin8

I want to filter the items in a Vaadin 8 `TreeGrid` based on a (user provided) search phrase and a back-end based (lazy loading) `HierarchicalDataProvider`.

I cannot find any references / examples how to realize the filtering part of this solution. I am looking for the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Please improve your question by adding relevant code.

Comment: Please post your data provider code. What is the actual source of data? Database?

Answer (score 2):

Basically your `HierarchicalDataProvider` must support this. See the [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-hierarchical.html#datamodel.hierarchical).
For the built-in `InMemoryHierarchicalDataProvider` a `setFilter` method is provided. For your own hierarchical data provider you could take the filter part of the `HierarchicalQuery` into account when implementing `fetchChildren` and the corresponding count method.